# Why UI5 sap.m.Text treat `\n` as blank?

Tags: sapui5

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5v9ZM8BbY2eIxbAUGTs2?p=preview)

```
<html:span>What I expect: test \n\n 123</html:span>
<Text text="test \n\n 123"/>
```

sap.m.Text viewed as `test 123` in the best situation, but what if I want `test \n\n 123`?

> Line breaks (\r\n, \n\r, \r, \n) will always be visualized except when the wrapping property is set to false. In addition, tabs (\t) and whitespace (" ") can be preserved by setting the renderWhitespace property to true
>   https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Text

Comment: created an issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/1973

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a different control, like [sap.m.FormattedText](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FormattedText/)

```
<FormattedText htmlText="test \n\n 123" />
```

Comment: Can you explain more about this behavior of Text ? Is this acceptable in our product?

Comment: Well I do not work for SAP and did not implement the Text control. But I assume it's working as intended. **Note:** The description of the `renderWhitespace` property is a little different from the text you copied: `Specifies how whitespace and tabs inside the control are handled. If true, whitespace will be preserved by the browser. Depending on wrapping property text will either only wrap on line breaks or wrap when necessary, and on line breaks.

Note: Special characters that can be used are : \t , \n and " " respectively Tab, New line and Space.`

Comment: The UI5 TextRenderer calls the Text.getText()-function in a way where the Text is "normalized" by 

    `return sText.replace(/\\r\\n|\\n/g, "\n");`

This automatically replaces all "\n" in your string.